# How To Get The Size Of A File (Hosted On A Web Server)?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, webclient, filesize

I am using the `WebClient` class to download an .exe file from a web server. Here is the code I am using to download the file:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();    
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.blah.com/calc.exe"));
```

My application has a ProgressBar which gets updated in the callback (`webClient_DownloadProgressChanged`):

```
private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived;
}
```

The problem I am having is I have to set the `Maximum` value for the progress bar dynamically. In other words I need to know the size of the file I am downloading *before* the download starts.

Is there a way to get the size of a file (before downloading it) given it's uri?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set max size to  e.TotalBytesToReceive like this

```
private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBar.Max = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    progressBar.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived;

}
```

Comment: Exactly wht I did! Thanks! As I said in my comment above, it is kindof sloppy to set the maximum value every time when in reality it should only be set once. But I suppose setting the maximum value over and over is better than using some kind of boolean to know when the first time you entered the callback.

Comment: Nice one for not suggesting to use `e.ProgressPercentage` despite it being *much* easier.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways will be checking for the Content-Length or the Range header in ResponseHeaders.

```
// To set the range
//webClient.Headers.Add("Range","bytes=-128");

// To read Content-Length
var bytes = Convert.ToInt64(webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. Can you elaborate a bit more? It looks like you are setting something whereas I would think you would need to be reading something from the header?

Comment: Actually I just discovered something.. in the callback webClient_DownloadProgressChanged the parameter e has a property called TotalBytesToReceive. Therefore all I have to do is set the maximum value for the progress bar the first time I enter the callback. Either that or I could just be lazy and set the maximum value each time the callback is called. This would eliminate the need for me to have some kind of boolean to know that it' the first time I entered the callback (which to me is hackish).

Comment: Sorry Trikks I accepted Arun's answer becasue he recommended exactly the solution I came up with. Thanks for your efforts though!

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to update progress bar correctly, the easiest way is to use `ProgressPercentage`

```
// progressBar.Max is always set to 100
progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```